# Windows authentication for the application and managed service account for sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, iis, asp-classic

I have an application which is a classic asp site with an application pool .NET v2.0 classic.

The site has been using windows authentication for the application and sql server authentication with a user name and password in the connection string for the database.
I want to switch the connectionstring to use a managed service account, so I replaced user and password in the connectionstring with Integrated Security=SSPI; I changed the application pool to run as the managed service account and I've installed the service account on the server.

Now my problem is my own window pricipal domain name shows up in the sql log e.g. contoso\camilla instead of the managed service account.

If I enable "Anonymous Authentication" on the application site in IIS and set "Application Pool Identity" as credential and restart the site, I see the managed service account in the sql log e.g contoso\myserviceAcc$.
How can I force the IIS to use the serviceaccount when only windows authentication is enabled?

Comment: I think this is more about MS Sql Server that anything else, so I added the tag.

Comment: You could do something like link the user name you want to see to the domain name in a table, and then when it detects that user's  domain account being loggin in, it instead uses the other value to pass for the sql log, unless the sql is doing the authetication instead of IIS?  And Asp Classic has a built in method to get the domain to do the lookup, so this would work.

Comment: Refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bsz5788z(v=vs.100)#to-configure-iis-for-windows-integrated-authentication.